# Trouble with a programming assignment Farm production

Tags: java

Develop a top-down design and write a program to produce a bar chart of gourmet-popcorn production for a cooperative farm group on a farm-by-farm basis.

- The input to the program is a series of data sets, one per line, with
  each set representing the production for one farm.
- Each data set consists of the name of a farm. Followed by a comma and
  one or more spaces, a decimal number representing acres planted, one
  or more spaces, and an integer representing the number of pint jars
  of popcorn produced for that farm.
- The output is a bar chart that identifies each farm and displays its
  production in pints of corn per acre.
- The output is a single line for each farm, with the name of the farm
  starting in the first column on a line and the bar chart starting in
  column 30. Each mark in the bar chart represents 25 pint jars of
  popcorn per acre.
- The production goal for the year is 500 jars per acre. A vertical bar
  should appear in the chart for farms with production that does not
  meet this goal, and a special mark is used for farms with production
  greater than or equal to 500 jars per acre.

**For example, given the input file**

```
Orville’s Acres, 114.8 43801
Hoffman’s Hills, 77.2 36229
Jiffy Quick Farm, 89.4 24812
Jolly Good Plantation, 183.2 104570
Organically Grown Inc., 45.5 14683
```

the output would be:

```
Popcorn Co-op
Production in Hundreds
of Pint Jars per Acre
Farm Name 1 2 3 4 5 6
---|---|---|---|---|---|
Orville's Acres *************** |
Hoffman's Hills ****************** |
Jiffy Quick Farm *********** |
Jolly Good Plantation *******************#**
Organically Grown Inc. ************ |
```

This is the code I have already it runs and prints the correct format but it has an exception error. I am trying to split a string up into the farm name then a double acres and finally a int jars. The input file is

```
Orville’s Acres, 114.8  43801
Hoffman’s Hills, 77.2  36229
Jiffy Quick Farm,       89.4  24812
Jolly Good Plantation,  183.2  104570
Organically Grown Inc., 45.5        14683
```

The reason for all the spaces is I want it just to read lines with data.

Here is my source code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Popcorn
{

public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
{

    printHeading(); 

    System.out.print("Input file name you want to read from: ");

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    

    String fileName = in.next();    //declares fileName a string that uses in as input

    Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));  //Declares input as the fileName and reads the file in

    int jars;
    double acres;
    String amount;
    String farmName;
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("\t\t\tPopcorn Co-op");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\tProduction in Hundreds");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\tof Pint Jars per Acre");
    System.out.println("Farm Name\t\t\t   1   2   3   4   5   6");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t---|---|---|---|---|---|");


    while (input.hasNextLine())
    {


        String inputLine = input.nextLine();    

        if (inputLine.isEmpty())
        {   

        }
        else 
        {
            farmName = inputLine.substring(0,inputLine.indexOf(','));
            String inputLine2 =  inputLine.substring(inputLine.indexOf(','),inputLine.length());
            Scanner line = new Scanner(inputLine2);
            acres = line.nextDouble();
            jars = line.nextInt();
            System.out.println(farmName + jars + acres);

        }

    }
}

private static void printHeading(){


    System.out.println("Name");  //this assigns what printHeading will print
    System.out.println("CSC 201-55468 Section 01PR");
    System.out.println("Fall 2012");
    System.out.println("Popcorn Project");
    System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this a question? Can you add the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String inputLine2 =  inputLine.substring(inputLine.indexOf(',') + 1);
```

This skips the comma, which the original line did not.

Maybe it is:

```
line.skip("[ \t]+");
```

that is needed to skip the space in front.

---

***After trying the code with indexOf+1 (without skip):***

```
...
Orville’s Acres43801114.8
Hoffman’s Hills3622977.2
Jiffy Quick Farm2481289.4
Jolly Good Plantation104570183.2
Organically Grown Inc.1468345.5
```

Which seems fine, considering:

```
            System.out.println(farmName + jars + acres);
```

As this seems homework, I leave it at that.

Comment: @JoopEggen.. What would one understand from that answer?? Where do you want it to put?? You should explain a little bit at least..

Comment: You are right @RohitJain, but when typing it, I saw the question was edited considerably - looking much more informative by the way. My line was a replacement for `String inputLine2 = ...`.

Comment: @JoopEggen.. And why exactly do you want it to get replaced?? You should tell that no?? Else OP will be more confused..

Comment: @MichaelTalbott.. Its good that you understood.. But I'm talking only in general case..

Comment: @ joopEggen I make that correction but it picks up the last number as a double I need the first number as a Double and last as an Integer

Comment: indexOf-comma + 1 should work. Aaah, maybe better `if (line.hasNextDouble()) { ... }`. But that should not be necessary.

Comment: when when i put that line.skip code into the program is give me a no such element exception.

Comment: I dont know how to copy and paste from the console window.

Comment: Thanks guys got it figured out

Comment: Didn't know you only needed one point to get a substring I always thought you needed a starting and end point